# Error after logging in, desktop is gone in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in a dual boot with Windows 8.1. It's the second time I boot Ubuntu and after logging in my session I get this error message :

```
Oops! Something went wrong. 
The name org.gtk.vfs.Daemon was not provided by any.service files
```

[image: Screenshot (in French)]

I can't right-click on the desktop and if I go in *Settings* -> *Personal* -> *Appearance* I see this:

[image: Screenshot (in French)]

Comment: What happens when you press `Alt`+`F2`? And enter `nautilus -n`?

Comment: What happens when you press [Ctrl][Alt][F1] and log in there? ([Ctrl][Alt][F7] to come back to the GUI)

Comment: @alexander255 `Alt`+`F2` is the shortcut for the search app right ? It opens but doesn't find anything if I type something. If I type `nautilus -n` in the terminal I get this message `(nautilus:2666): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`

Comment: @Fabby If I log in with the terminal I'm still on the GUI login screen when I come back to the GUI.

Comment: Excellent! At least you can now look at the logs to see *why* it doesn't work.  Could you log into the terminal (TTY1 à partir de maintenant) and type `sudo reboot` (to clear the logs and start afresh) and then before you even try to log on, go to TTY1 again, log in and type `dmesg`.  Then, take a picture (with a camera, not a phone!) of the screen an post the picture anywhere on the web and post a link to the picture in a comment?

Comment: @Fabby There you go [Image 1](http://imgur.com/Cj8V825) [Image 2](http://imgur.com/7Gymoxi)

Comment: This doesn't tell us much...  Could you do a : `dmesgs | more` and post pics of the first three screens?  (unfortunately I'm going to sleep now, but I'll upvote your question so that it attracts more people) 1 horizontal pic per screen is fine: resolution is high enough to be read.  Don't use flash and take it from a 25 degree angle left or right.

Comment: @Fabby Update : I couldn't boot Windows on top of my issue with Ubuntu (murphy's law I guess =p). So I used a Ubuntu USB key to recover all my files and I'm going to format my HD and reinstall everything. But thank you very much for trying to help me. This community is awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please boot into a USB/LiveCD and copy the

```
/home/media/ubuntu/UID/var/log/dmesg
```

from there and post it in your question.

We'll take it from there to recover all your files so you can start afresh.